# How to pass data from viewcontroller A to another viewcontroller B using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am creating instance of ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: String)` function.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcB") as VCB;
rootController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


class VCB: UIViewController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

}
```

I want to access value which i have passed in my ViewControllerB how can i achieve this.

*i alredy gone through 
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) link but the answers in objective c.*

Comment: There are lot of ways you can pass data from one view controller to another viewcontroller like using NSNotification center,delegate,PrepareforSegue,and using Propertylist

Comment: The question you linked has many Swift answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can declare a `var` in your `VCB` viewController and inject data to this property

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcB") as VCB;

vc.yourData = SOME_DATA

rootController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


class VCB: UIViewController {

var yourData: AnyObject?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

}
```

Comment: do i have to import my viewcontrollerB in viewcontrollerA?

Comment: @Ashok no you don't need to.

Comment: **value of type 'UIViewController' has no memebr 'yourData' error**

Comment: I have two files one is viewcontrollerA.swift and another one is viewcontrollerB.swift

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
import UIKit
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func passDataAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UIViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB;
    vc.dataFromOtherView = "The data is passed"
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

And the other class

```
import UIKit
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

var dataFromOtherView: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    print(dataFromOtherView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: from where I have to call passDataAction method ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code send data from one view controller to anotherview controller

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc=storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondView") as! ViewControllerB;
vc.dataFromOtherView = "The data is passed"
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```